# How to override a function in every instance for unit tests in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, unit-testing, overriding

I have a function, `Foo`, and already used in `Bar` and some other places in the Python package. And for the unit test, I need to replace that function with `fake_Foo`. The `fake_Foo` should override every previous instance. How to do that?

I have tried `Foo = fake_Foo` and `global Foo` but it does not work.

TL;DR: I am trying to override [`_command` function here](https://github.com/eftalgezer/SIESTAstepper/blob/main/SIESTAstepper/core.py) with [`fake_command` function here](https://github.com/eftalgezer/SIESTAstepper/blob/main/tests/testers.py) for every previous instance.

Comment: note, you don't need `file.close()` when using a with statement, just for future reference.

Comment: Nice idea, but the _command substitution will not be in place whenever a routine outside the module calls it.  I think I see some of the tests call a high-level routine which, probably? imports the _command routine from the original module/source.   It is more conventional to setup proper unittests and mock, or use pytest `monkeypatch`, to substitute in the fake routine.

Comment: On SO, rather than some links to code elsewhere and hoping for help to debug your work, you get a better reaction to your question if you boil the problem down to its essence and present the minimum.  People are better drawn into a little self contained 'puzzle' that needs solving then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it with:

```
from _pytest.monkeypatch import MonkeyPatch

def fake_Foo(monkeypatch=MonkeyPatch()):

    def fake__Foo(args):
        ...

    monkeypatch.setattr("module.Foo", fake__Foo)
```

Just call `fake_Foo()` when you need to override.